# Concise GPL requirements summary list

Tags: gpl, apache-2.0

I find [the current version of the GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html) to be relatively short and easy to read. However, some people seem to see a [wall of text](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text) and cannot get through it. Thus [we have](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1889/is-requiring-a-license-a-violation-of-the-gpl-can-i-get-around-it) many [questions asked](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/176/do-i-really-need-to-include-a-licence-file-for-common-licences-like-gpl-or-mit) here [that are](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/35/if-i-include-some-gpl-code-in-my-project-can-i-release-it-as-bsd) specifically [addressed](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1399/can-gpl-licenced-software-be-used-in-corporate-environments) in the text. **People don't seem to have the attention span for 14 screenfulls of text.**

The [Apache license](http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html) has a terrific summary on the webpage for the license:

> It allows you to:
>
> - freely download and use Apache software, in whole or in part, for personal, company internal, or commercial purposes;
> - use Apache software in packages or distributions that you create.
>
> It forbids you to:
>
> - redistribute any piece of Apache-originated software without proper attribution;
> - use any marks owned by The Apache Software Foundation in any way that might state or imply that the Foundation endorses your distribution;
> - use any marks owned by The Apache Software Foundation in any way that might state or imply that you created the Apache software in question.
>
> It requires you to:
>
> - include a copy of the license in any redistribution you may make that includes Apache software;
> - provide clear attribution to The Apache Software Foundation for any distributions that include Apache software.
>
> It does not require you to:
>
> - include the source of the Apache software itself, or of any modifications you may have made to it, in any redistribution you may assemble that includes it;
> - submit changes that you make to the software back to the Apache Software Foundation (though such feedback is encouraged).

Is there a similar list of bullet points compiled for the GPL or other FOSS licenses, such as MIT?

Comment: The MIT license wouldn't need it, any explanation would be longer than the license itself.

Comment: @curiousdannii: The [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/about/) too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GPL is a much more intricate license than the Apache license, and the MIT/Expat license is much simpler.

The MIT License reads

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
>   of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
>   in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
>   to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
>   copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
>   furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
>   all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

It's too short to usefully make a point by point list.

The GPL is more intricate than the Apache license, which may not be as suitable for a bulleted list approach. The FSF releases [a FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html), which is something. Some others have attempted to do this though, for example tldrlegal tries to do so for many licenses. It's overview of the GPLv3 is here: https://tldrlegal.com/license/gnu-general-public-license-v3-(gpl-3)

Such a list is no replacement for the actual license text, but may give you a quick idea.

Comment: Thank you Martijn, that list is exactly what I was looking for.